# How to access GitLab repository graph using CURL?

Tags: curl, gitlab

I Would like to automate generate git branch image using bash. One way is to directly download svg file on gitlab url:

```
http://GITIP/PROJECTID/network/master
```

Is there any api call like below to get image? thanks.

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" http://GITLAB/api/v4/projects/GETGRAPH?
```

[image]

Comment: I don't believe there is an API endpoint specifically for downloading the graph. However, GitLab uses Raphael.js so if you wanted to, you could look at the codebase to see how GitLab does it and generate it locally: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/app%2Fassets%2Fjavascripts%2Fnetwork%2Fbranch_graph.js